# How to save information about the position of a clicked item in recyclerview after re-entering the app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences

how can I save information about the position of the clicked recyclerview element? I need to highlight the clicked recyclerview element and save this selection after closing the app. I tried to do this by creating a booleanArray and changing the value to true by clicking on the element. But how can I save this array so that after re-entering the application, the values are not reset?

Adaptor

```
class UsersAdapter(private val videoTitles: List<String>,
               private val Trening: List<String>,
               private val clickListener: onClickRecyclerViewItem,
               private val array: BooleanArray
               ): RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersAdapter.CustomViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {
    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, parent, false)
    return CustomViewHolder(cellForRow)
}


@SuppressLint("ShowToast")
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val videoTitle = videoTitles[position]
    val Trening1 = Trening[position]
    holder.view.name.text= videoTitle
    holder.view.quantity.text= Trening1
    holder.view.setOnClickListener {
        clickListener.onClickItemListener()
        array[position] = true }
    }

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return videoTitles.size
}



@SuppressLint("ShowToast")
class CustomViewHolder(val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
}
}
```

Comment: Use Sharedpreferences to save the array

Answer (score 0):

You can save your item clicked in the sharepreferences or in room database and when you come back you can get the data from these and use as you wants.
This [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm) show you how to use sharepreferences and [this](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-room-database-example/) show how to implements room database

Answer (score 0):

When closing the app, all information aka fragments / activities etc. are destroyed. If you want to save a specific value after closing the app, you can either create a room-database (which is kinda overkill for this purpose), or save the value in the shared-preferences. I advise you to look [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) to know more about saving data in android.